# Approximation of Heaviside function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, numerical-methods, fourier-series, approximation

I have a Heaviside function here.
$$H(x):=\begin{cases}
1, & x > 0\\
0, & x=0\\
-1, & x<0
\end{cases}$$

I want to approximate this function by polynomial of degree 2 on (-1,1). The hint I got from my professor is the following:

$$H_n=C_n\int_0^xcos^n(\frac{\pi}{2}t)dt, x∈[−1,1]$$  with a normalizing constant $C_n:=\int_0^1cos^n(\frac{π}{2}t)dt.$

Then, one can show that $∥H_n−H∥_{L^2_w[a,b]}<ϵ$ for large enough n.

I don't really know how to show this since I think as $n$ approches infinity, $C_n$ would be approchinng $0$. I don't know if I got the integration wrong but I'm really confused.

Comment: by the way, what you defined is not the Heaviside function, but rather the "sign" function.

Comment: Should it be a single polynomial of degree 2? Then it must be $cx$ due to oddness of $H(x)$. If using splines you can be arbitrary close to $H(x)$ in the L2 sense

Comment: @uranix yes it's a single polynomial. What do you mean by cx and splines?

Comment: Do you mean an "algebraic" polynomial or a trigonometric polynomial? $y=cx$ with $c$ somewhere between $1$ and $2$ might be the best in the algebraic case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think I need to use taylor expansion for $H_n$ to get the final explicit expression of the polynomial. So it would be algebraic I guess. I still don't get what you mean by cx since I need a degree 2 polynomial.

Comment: $H(x)$ is an odd function. A quadratic $P_2(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2$. The $c_0$ and $c_2x^2$ are even terms, so they can not appear in least squares L2 approximation which is obtained by $\|H(x) - P_2(x) \|^2 \to \min_{c_0, c_1, c_2}$.